# Resampling and interpolating raster according the coordinates

Tags: python, scipy, geospatial, gdal, python-xarray

I have six field spot measurements with specific coordinates and then drone imagery with quite high resolution for the same area. I am looking for a function or script which will resample and interpolate drone imagery (in GeoTIFF) ideally to the six pixels with the same or with the closest coordinates as possible to the coordinates of the field measurements.

I was a little bit googling but not successful to find something promising. I was trying the `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, however not quite sure if it is considering the coordinates. I hope that I was able to describe the issue sufficiently.

I provide a code/data snippet for the Python solution.

Code snippet (imported by xarray):

```
date1_field_mes
Out:
  Measured_val lat     lon
0 8            49.7316 15.5400
1 10           49.7313 15.5393
3 15           49.7320 15.5354
4 12           49.7313 15.5375
5 14           49.7310 15.5408
6 6            49.7337 15.5350

Drone_image
Out:
       Value lat     lon
 0     8     49.7311 15.5415
 1     9     49.7317 15.5418
 .     .     ....... .......
 1500  21    49.7339 15.5354
```

Expected output (Something like this):

```
 Drone_image
 Out:
   value   lat     lon
 0 8.5     49.7316 15.5400
 1 10.1    49.7313 15.5393
 3 14.2    49.7320 15.5354
 4 13.3    49.7313 15.5375
 5 10.4    49.7310 15.5408
 6 6       49.7337 15.5350
```

Many thanks!

Edit:

My code:

```
points = Drone_image[['lat','lon']].to_numpy()
values = Drone_image['Value'].to_numpy()

grid_x = date1_field_mes[['lat']].to_numpy()
grid_y = date1_field_mes[['lon']].to_numpy()

grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y),method='cubic')
```

grid_z0 contains 6 values array. Is that it? Could I use it with `lat` and `lon` of `date1_field_mes`?

Comment: Hi Lukáš, please show your coding attempt at using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` and why you think it is not giving the right answer.

Comment: @RobertDavy I provided my code snippet. I hope that my question is clear. I am not quite sure about the coordinates.